# Can't throwaway result of a val1 && val2?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do something like

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly Random r = new Random();

    public static void Main()
    {
        RandomBool() && RandomBool();
    }

    private static bool RandomBool()
    {
        bool b = r.Next() % 2 == 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Random bool value is {0}", b);
        return b;
    }
}
```

i.e. execute `RandomBool()` until it's `false`. (You can do this in JavaScript)

I guess I have to do

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool throwAwayValue = RandomBool() && RandomBool();
}
```

Or is there a better way to do the same thing?

Comment: "i.e. execute RandomBool() until it's false." - but that's not what you're doing, you're just executing it twice.

Comment: What you want to try i can not understand your question could you elaborate?

Comment: If you want to do something until something is `false`, you should write a `while` loop. That's as true in C# as it is in JavaScript.

Comment: I guess this is for learning purposes, isn't it? If there is a real requirement, there is probably a better way to do what you want.

Comment: "You can do this in JavaScript" no you really can't. I mean sure you can do it, just as you can in c#, but this code won't.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to execute `RandomBool` repeatedly until it's false, can't you use while loop in your `main`?

```
while (RandomBool()) { 
    // wait
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while

Comment: Why not just `while (RandomBool());`?

Comment: Is that correct syntax? I've never misused `while` in that way. And maybe OP want's to execute some code or wait (because I don't see any practical usage in this)

Comment: That's valid syntax, yes. Based on the whole question being about throwing away the result, I think that OP doesn't want to execute code or wait. OP just wants to call the method until it returns true.

Comment: In that case, that would be possible too. But like I said, I don't see any practical use if you aren't doing anything with the value nor waiting in the while loop. This `while` will exit in no time, so what's the point? But I should have to ask OP instead.

Comment: I'm 100% with you on that. I don't see why the loop isn't around the code _inside_ the `RandomBool` method if OP wants to print boolean values until `false` is reached.